# How to dynamically access formControl in a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I need to display an error list for certain fields on an Angular reactive form.
I'm trying to dynamically reference a FormControl to check if it has an error,
but I can't seem to get the *ngIf expression to evaluate.

```
<ul *ngIf="myFormGroup.invalid">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.formFieldsToCheck | keyvalue" >
    <li *ngIf="myFormGroup.controls[item.key].invalid"> {{item.value}} </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

I've tried every combination of ', ", {}, (), [] with item.key that I can imagine.

Comment: What exactly is `this.formFieldsToCheck`?

Comment: it's an object. Just a list of the FormGroupControl names (key) and a string to display (value)

Comment: Should work unless your formFieldsToCheck have elements that not defined in your FormControl. Use the "safe operator" :`<li *ngIf="myFormGroup.controls[item.key]?.invalid">` -the `?` between the "[item.key]" and ".invalid", and check the value of formFieldsToCheck a [little example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjbxua?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: OMG, I can't believe it was just a ? mark!
Thank you so much Eliseo. You are, of course, absolutely right.
All of the control names were correct, but some of them were defined on myForm2,
and therefore were invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a getter in your ts file:

```
get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl; } {
    return this.myFormGroup.controls;
}
```

And access the form value in html with:

```
f['item.key'].touched
```

Also, for a better approach to manage errors in reactive forms use `mat-error`.
Example:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="f['property'].touched && f['property'].invalid">
    <span translate>Property is required</span>
</mat-error>
```